# The method visible() is undefined for the type ActivityController

Tags: android, robolectric

I am using robolectric unit testing of android application when i am using the the line below

```
ActivityMain  activityMain = Robolectric.buildActivity(ActivityMain.class)
                    .create()
                    .visible()
                    .get();
```

Its giving me The method visible() is undefined for the type ActivityController error.

Note i am using `robolectric-2.0-alpha-3-jar-with-dependencies.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the older version `robolectric-2.0-alpha-3-jar-with-dependencies.jar` which does not contain `visible()`after using `robolectric-2.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar` it was working.for information check [this](http://robolectric.blogspot.in/2013/10/robolectric-22-released.html)